# Generating correct url for page link

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have implemented pagation in my Spring boot application. There are no problems in the logic of it, however I am running into a weird issue with Thymeleaf.

Right now if I go to the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/Phoenix-listings
```

and if I hover my mouse over the link to page 2 is

```
http://localhost:8080/2
```

which is the wrong link, but if I manually go to the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/Phoenix-listings/1
```

then if I hover my mouse over page 2, then the link is

```
http://localhost:8080/Phoenix-listings/2
```

which is how it should be.

How can I make the correct link get generated even if I am in `http://localhost:8080/Phoenix-listings`?

Below is the section related to my pagation in Thymeleaf

```
<div class="row">
    <div th:if="${ads.totalPages != 1}"
        class="form-group col-md-11 pagination-centered">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li th:class="${ads.number == 0} ? disabled"><a
                class="pageLink" th:href="1">&laquo;</a></li>
            <li th:class="${ads.number == 0} ? disabled"><a
                class="pageLink" th:href="${ads.number}">&larr;</a></li>
            <li
                th:class="${ads.number == (page - 1)} ? 'active pointer-disabled'"
                th:each="page : ${#numbers.sequence(pager.startPage, pager.endPage)}">
                <a class="pageLink" th:href="${page}" th:text="${page}"></a>
            </li>
            <li th:class="${ads.number + 1 == ads.totalPages} ? disabled">
                <a class="pageLink" th:href="${ads.number + 2}">&rarr;</a>
            </li>
            <li th:class="${ads.number + 1 == ads.totalPages} ? disabled">
                <a class="pageLink" th:href="${ads.totalPages}">&raquo;</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should be using thymeleaf's built in [url syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls).  It would look like this:

```
th:href="@{/{page}(page=${page})}"
```

Creating a link with `@{/}` means that thymeleaf automatically adds the context (`Phoenix-listings` in your case.) `{page}` is a placeholder. `(page=${page})` replaces the placeholder with the variable.

You can also use string concatenation, but I wouldn't recommend it in most cases (because using the standard syntax means thymeleaf can correctly encode urls).

```
th:href="@{${'/' + page}}"
```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately it's not working, now if I go to  `http://localhost:8080/Phoenix-listings/1` or `http://localhost:8080/Phoenix-listings` the link generated is `http://localhost:8080/2`

Comment: `Phoenix-listings` isn't your application context?  Then you're going to have to add it to your links like this: `th:href="@{/Phoenix-listings/{page}(page=${page})}"` (or always make sure they arrive at Phoenix-listings/ with a slash) -- that's just the way html works.

Comment: I store `Phoenix-listings` in cityForPage, I tried `@{/{cityForPage}(page=${page})}` but it's not putting the value of "cityForPage" but it's putting `http://localhost:8080/%7BcityForPage%7D?page=2`

Comment: That should be `@{${'/' + cityForPage + '/{page}'}(page=${page})}` (edited)